# Where do the jQuery includes in my header come from?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-6.2.x

Somehow my jQuery include gets overwritten by an older version that makes my .on function cause an error (at least I think so). I can't find out where that include is coming from.
I want to delete it and control my includes from my root-templates and the setup.txt of my extensions.
I commented out everything in my root-template and only left this standing (found it on [here](https://jweiland.net/typo3/codebeispiele/typoscript/javascript-manuell-entfernen-oder-einbinden.html)):

```
page = PAGE
page.includeJS >
page.includeJSlibs >
page.includeJSFooter >
page.includeJSFooterlibs >
page.jsInline >
page.jsFooterInline >
```

And this is the outcome in my header:

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/fileadmin/icons/lc_icon.png" type="image/png; charset=binary">
<link rel="icon" href="/fileadmin/icons/lc_icon.png" type="image/png; charset=binary">
<title>Home</title>
<meta name="generator" content="TYPO3 CMS">


<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="typo3temp/stylesheet_15e5175da3.css?1468240242" media="all">






<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
```

Does someone know how I can track down where all those script and link tags come from?

EDIT:
I found it in the template analyzer which I didn't know about before (I installed it first but then realized it was there before already because I suddenly had two entries "Template Analyzer" in my select after the install).
[image]
And this was where the jQuery includes came from:

```
EXT:fluid/Configuration/TypoScript

2379: [GLOBAL]
2380:  # includes jQuery library and default styles for Fluid Autocomplete Widget
2381: page.headerData.998 = TEXT
2382: page.headerData.998.value (
2383:   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6/jquery.min.js"></script>
2384:   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
2385:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
2386:   <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://static.jquery.com/ui/css/demo-docs-theme/ui.theme.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
2387: )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the options you already ruled out, head data can be included through

```
page.headerData
```

([see reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Setup/Page/Index.html#headerdata))

Look this up in the Template Analyzer to find out if and which exact template includes it. If you can rule that out as well, it might be an include from an extension class. The easiest way to find it then would be to run a `grep` on your command line:

```
grep -Ri "ajax.googleapis.com" /typo/root/folder
```

Comment: thanks didn't know about the template analyzer -
but do you think it is save if I just delete those includes (see edited question)? Should be, since it's just for a Fluid Autocomplete Widget which I never noticed because I don't have any auto completion except in Netbeans.

Comment: The Fluid Autocomplete Widget is a widget that could be used in an Extbase extension to provide autocomplete ("search" as you type) functionality. Unless you use it in one of your extensions, you can safely remove it from the loaded TypoScript.

Comment: thanks, I thought it was for code completion, you've made it clear to me now!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot remove the template you can put this in your own typoscript:

```
page.headerData.998 >
```